# Ubuntu have direcotry be owned by mysql - how to change owner

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a directory in ubuntu.  I need to have it look like the below.

```
drwx------  2 mysql root      4096 Feb  4 15:18 mysql
```

Right now it is

```
drwx------  2 root root
```

Is this a chown command?

I am trying to move the data directory for mysql to /data/my

Comment: Does it really look like that? If it has no size / timetamp or name then there's something very wrong with your filesystem.

Comment: Not knowing the chown command speaks volumes about your inexperience with Linux. If this new database install is to be used in a professional manner (which we can all safely assume), then I would suggest you have someone with more experience look over your setup when you're done. If one of my employees were to ask this question, my response would be "Whatever you're doing... don't!" If it's something you have to do, good luck. Ubuntu has great documentation for those that are new to Linux. I highly suggest it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `chown mysql mysql`

But why do you need this? Installing MySQL on Ubuntu adapts the permissions during installation.